# Not the normal Failed to decrypt protected XML node "DTS:Password"

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I got the:

> Failed to decrypt XML node "DTS:Password" with error 0c8009000B "Key
>   not valid for use in specified state." bla bla bla

error on the server today.  The thing is this is a **job that has been in production since 3/16/14 running daily and never had this issue before**.  I had the server re-run it with no changes and it worked.

I have searched on this error and all I can find are questions from people who don't know/understand about protection level settings.  I could not find anything about a production job that throws this error after working for 5 months.  I would like to figure out why this happened so I can prevent it from happing again.  I don't like having random ticking time bombs in my system.  Any ideas/suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: The error message is not related to the job. SQL Agent merely executes the packages in a timely and organized manner. The failure was with the package itself (DTS:Password is your biggest hint that it was package related). Maybe some connection could not be evaluated at the time of execution? FTP site down? Host of reasons could play a part.

Comment: So it is possible that this is the wrong error message?  Meaning that the package could not connect to server X so instead of a can't find/open database type error it threw this decrypt error?  Seems odd but I have seen worse from Microsoft.

Comment: The error message is ok. Sometimes, while importing/exporting packages out of SQL Server, the password gets mucked up. Any possibility someone touched the package in any way? If no one touched the package, then you may want to escalate this to MSFT. But yes, MS has done things in a much horrible way for many things.

Comment: The last modified date is what it should be and I am the only dev so I would say no one else touched it.  It is connecting to an AS400 which is connected to by a dozens of other jobs that all ran fine, most have the password in plaintext.  The AS400 people had no reported issues at the time.  There are no error messages in the event viewer other then that the package failed.  Don't know if it is worth talking to MSFT as I don't have much info to go on and I can't replicate the error.  I have been removing plain text passwords and storing them in the SQL Job, maybe I should do so for this job?

Comment: That would be a good idea. Since no one changed it, I suspect it to be an underlying bug. Here's a link to an old discussion about the same issue. You would'nt believe the reason it errored out with this error message. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935483/ssis-just-started-getting-a-key-not-valid-for-use-in-specified-state-error-o/12940817#12940817