# SSIS 08 job runs a SSRS 08 report but fails when ran in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssis

I have created an SSIS package (08) that has a script task which runs an SSRS report (08) with given parameters. The report creates a pdf version of the file on a file share drive of my choosing.

When I run the SSIS manually it works perfectly, however, when I upload SSIS into SQL and then run it from the job agent it fails.  It gives a long error message but the basic piece is;

> (0xC0016016     Source:        Description: Failed to decrypt
>   protected XML node "DTS:Property" with error 0x8009000B "Key not valid
>   for use in specified state.".  You may not be authorized to access
>   this information. This error occurs when there is a cryptographic
>   error. Verify that the correct key is available.   End Error
>
> Error: 2018-01-15 16:09:58.28     Code: 0xC001600C
>   Source:
>   PackageSchedule Connection manager "ReportServer08"
>   Description:
>   Server authentication failed. This error occurs when login credentials
>   are not provided, or the credentials are incorrect. )

I have tried to change the `"ProtectionLevel"` to `"EncryptSensitiveWithPassword"` and also "Donset upSensitive".

I setup a subscription to the report just to make sure it wasn't a read/write error to the specific folder and the subscription ran without error as well.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're on the right track with your troubleshooting but when you created the subscription to test r/w access, did you use the same account that is also running the SQL Agent?

Comment: Check out this KB:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/918760/ssis-package-does-not-run-when-called-from-a-sql-server-agent-job-step

Answer (score 0):

According to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12956779/3266499) the issue was related to a date type issue. You could be experiencing the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Thank-you for the feedback.  I was able to figure it out.  On Import of the package to SQL itself I changed the 'Protection Level' to 'Rely on server storage and roles for access control'.  This allowed the job to execute successfully and everything looks great!