# "Key not valid for use in specified state." - SSIS Package

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, etl, sql-agent-job

I have a SSIS package deployed in my server. My database is a SQL Server 2008R2, the SSIS was developed in Data Tools 2008.

It used to work perfectly but since a few days it started to throw this error:

> Failed to decrypt protected XML node "DTS:Password" with error 0x8009000B "Key not valid for use in specified state.". You may not be authorized to access this information. This error occurs when there is a cryptographic error. Verify that the correct key is available.  End Error  Error: 2018-03-27 15:15:37.25     Code: 0xC0016016     Source:       Description: Failed to decrypt protected XML node "DTS:Password" with error 0x8009000B "Key not valid for use in specified state.". You may not be authorized to access this information. This error occurs when there is a cryptographic error. Verify that the correct key is available.  End Error  Error: 2018-03-27 15:15:37.84     Code: 0xC0202009     Source: Package Connection manager "MYDATABASE"     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E4D.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E4D  Description: "Login failed for user 'MYUSER'.".  End Error  Error: 2018-03-27 15:15:37.84     Code: 0xC020801C     Source: XX     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "MYDATABASE" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.  End Error  Error: 2018-03-27 15:15:37.84     Code: 0xC0047017     Source: Carga      criticidad SSIS.Pipeline     Description: component "XX" (1) failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.    Description: One or more component failed validation.  End Error  Error: 2018-03-27 15:15:37.84     Code: 0xC0024107     Source: XX      Description: There were errors during task validation.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1)

I already checked this post: [SSIS: Just started getting a "Key not valid for use in specified state." error on my scheduled SSIS package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935483/ssis-just-started-getting-a-key-not-valid-for-use-in-specified-state-error-o)

And i think it isn't the same because if a execute my ETL from the Data Tools, it works just fine. It only throws error when it executes by the SQL Agent

Does anyone know what could be this? I haven't changed anyuthing in the Server, Database or SSIS Package.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSIS: Just started getting a "Key not valid for use in specified state." error on my scheduled SSIS package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935483/ssis-just-started-getting-a-key-not-valid-for-use-in-specified-state-error-o)

Comment: It is not the same case. I already checked that post. Thank you

Comment: Did yo create a credential and used it in proxy account to run ssis package via agent job ?

Comment: Prabhat No I didn't. What should I do?